# How to change image every 4 seconds with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Sorry if I don't ask well, it's my first time.

I want to change the image every 4 seconds of this link: https://picsum.photos/200 that every time the page or the status is refreshed, the image is changed.

I have tried to do it with a second state that is a counter with `setInterval` and use `useEffec`t in the update phase of the [counter] but I am stuck.
This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const [photo,setPhoto] = useState('https://picsum.photos/200')

  useEffect(()=>{
    setPhoto(photo)
  },[])

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Photo:</h1>
      <img src={photo}></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something that changes the url each time you want to change the image.

A common approach, is to use a timestamp and append it at the end of the image `src` attribute, tricking the browser into thinking it is different image (*and thus not using the cached version*).

You can use `setInterval` to repeat the process every 4 seconds.

```
export default function App() {
  const photo = "https://picsum.photos/200";
  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState(Date.now());

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTimestamp(Date.now());
    }, 4000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Photo:</h1>
      <img src={`${photo}?_=${timestamp}`} alt="random"></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-browser-17gw1z

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Try to replace your useEffect with this one:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setPhoto(photo)
},[photo])
```

useEffect hook take a second params called dependency array, where this dependency array is what matter for the inner callback(inisde useEffect) to access the latest values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup interval to change url way you want.. in my demo it will just increment

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState("https://picsum.photos/200");
  const i = useRef(200);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = setInterval(() => {
      i.current += 1; //here should be some more soffisticated url creation
      setPhoto(`https://picsum.photos/${i.current}`);
    }, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(handle);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Photo:</h1>
      <img src={photo}></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

working demo:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/fervent-dream-tq0xng